# Ошибка компиляции C

Tags: c

Чего-то я не понял, если вводить буквы по все нормально, а если числа то при вводе второго числа приложение закрывается, почему? %d это же для int, вообщем попал в ступор.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
main()
{
 int a, b, c;     
 printf ( "Введите числа \n" );
 scanf ( "%d%d", a, b );
 c = a + b;
 printf ( "Вы ввели: %d и %d \n", &a, &b );
 printf ( "Их сумма = %d", &c );
 getch();    
}
```

Comment: Там вроде надо перед a и b амперсанды поставить. `scanf ( "%d%d", &a, &b );` В сканф аргументы надо по указателям передавать.

Comment: разобрался, забыл про указатели адреса переменных

Comment: В начале со всеми такое...

Comment: Ну, ошибок **компиляции** тут нет.

По делу. В scanf() нужны адреса переменных (амперсанды, как Вам сказали), а вот в printf() наоборот.

Еще один совет. scanf() возвращает количество успешно (в смысле преобразований формата) прочитанных аргументов. Проверяйте это число и если оно не соответствует ожидаемому, то 

1) прочтите все символы до конца строки (например fgets()) 

2) попросите юзера повторить ввод (или просто завершитесь с сообщением об ошибке).

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` работает с указателями,

```
scanf( "%d%d", &a, &b );
```

А `printf` нет,

```
printf( "Вы ввели: %d и %d \n", a, b );
```

Answer (score 2):

Верно так:

```
scanf( "%d%d", &a, &b );
```

Для примера:

```
/* scanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  int i;

  printf ("Enter your family name: ");
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  printf ("Enter your age: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  printf ("Mr. %s , %d years old.\n",str,i);
  printf ("Enter a hexadecimal number: ");
  scanf ("%x",&i);
  printf ("You have entered %#x (%d).\n",i,i);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anxis все верно написал. Только учтите что введенная вами строка не должна быть больше 79байт! (не символов, а именно байт.

- Один байт уходит на '0' (символ окончания строки в C/C++)
- В [unicode](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)  длина символов != размеру занимаемому в памяти

В качестве эксперимента попробуйте ввести строку больше 79символов.